# Is there a table for visual properties of common elements?

Tags: materials

I'm a noob at modeling or art in general, but I need to design a basic room. I can "design" the physical bodies, but I'm confused what values to apply to an object to make it look like, say, glass or water.

Are there any "canonical" values for reflectivity and RGB?

Comment: Well, yes and no. These properties vary based on a *lot* of factors, and often result in a very small visual difference that isn't very significant artistically. I usually google for a value when I want one, then tweak it until I like the look. But such tables exists, and IIRC there are some addons which put them right in blender. Luxrender even comes with some built in presets.

Comment: I think the best way is find some basic materials in web..like: [http://www.blender-materials.com/engine/blender-cycles](http://www.blender-materials.com/engine/blender-cycles) also you should be decide apply cycles or internal

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is about physical properties and not Blender